# Cannot find My New Solr Configset (Solr Cloud 7.3.0)

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am migrating from solfr 4.7 to solr cloud 7.3.0. I am trying to create a new custom configset set based on a default (_default) that came with the installation. I followed the instructions and used the following call:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/configs?action=CREATE&name=mySolrCloudConfigSet&baseConfigSet=_default
```

,getting the following response:

```
{
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":202}
}
```

, which I believe indicates success. I cannot find the new configset where I would have expected to find it (i.e., ~solr-7.3.0\server\solr\configsets). This is where the _default configset is located. More specifically, I cannot find my created configset anywhere under solr-7.3.0.

I am pretty certain I created it becuase when I execute the request to list all configsets:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/configs?action=LIST
```

, I see my configset in the response:

```
{
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":1},
"configSets":["_default",
"mySolrCloudConfigSet"]
}
```

I need to be able to find the configset on the filesystem so I can update the schema.xml file with my system's customizations.

I would be grateful for any ideas. Thanks

Comment: If you're running in cloud mode, the config sets are stored in Zookeeper since they need to be available (and identical) for all the nodes.  Have you checked there?

Comment: Thanks. I understand that now. I see them in zookeeper. thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

Since asking the question, I learned that solr cloud stores configsets directly into zookeeper, and not on filesystem. I was assuming it stored them on disk as with the old master-slave setup of the version 4.7 of solr we were previously using.